# How do I make an HTML element hidden by default?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a function to show my `span#note-` element when `span#note` is clicked. I want to make `span#note-` hidden by default, but I can't.

My code:

```
<h1>Republic of Labrador<br>Sub-Presidential Elections <span onclick="showOnClick()" id="note" title="Not all candidates are listed, and the vote ratioes for the listed candidates are approximated.
            Hover over a candidate's name to see their vote ratio.">&#9432;</span></h1>
    <br>
    <span id="note-">Not all candidates are listed, and the vote ratioes for the listed candidates
        are approximated.<br>Hover over a candidate's name to see their vote ratio.</span>
    <script>

        function showOnClick() {
            var x = document.getElementById("note-");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

My attempt at hiding `span#note-` by default:

```
<span id="note-" onload="hideOnLoad()">Not all candidates are listed, and the vote ratioes for the listed candidates
        are approximated.<br>Hover over a candidate's name to see their vote ratio.</span>
    <script>
        function hideOnLoad() {
            var y = document.getElementById("note-");
            y.style.display = "none";
        }
        function showOnClick() {
            var x = document.getElementById("note-");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

I expected `span#note-` to be hidden by default.

Comment: Did you try `<span id="note-" style="display: none">`?

Comment: @PrerakSola I just tried it, and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Willam Rock I know you're brand new here. Ideally, if you received a working solution and answer to your question, or more than one, please select the best answer as the Accepted Solution so that others who search and find this in the future know which solution to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to call your hideOnLoad() function. Either way I think you should hide the element by using CSS by using style="display: none;".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

`onLoad` only works on external resources such as images or the  tag. If you want to keep your second example, you'll have to move the onLoad="hideOnLoad()" attribute all the way up to the body tag.

The simpler solution would be to just hide it as part of the initial style of the element `style="display:none;` in the html. Below is your first example with the  element updated.

```
<h1>Republic of Labrador<br>Sub-Presidential Elections <span onclick="showOnClick()" id="note" title="Not all candidates are listed, and the vote ratioes for the listed candidates are approximated.
            Hover over a candidate's name to see their vote ratio.">&#9432;</span></h1>
    <br>
    <span id="note-" style="display: none;">Not all candidates are listed, and the vote ratioes for the listed candidates
        are approximated.<br>Hover over a candidate's name to see their vote ratio.</span>
    <script>

        function showOnClick() {
            var x = document.getElementById("note-");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**The easiest way to hide an element by default is with the CSS `display` property**

You can simply add a CSS rule inline inside the HTML tag. Or you can follow better practice and create a separate CSS file.

**1. Inline Rule:**

Simply add a `style` attribute to your tag.

```
<span id="note-" style="display:none;">any content here will not be displayed on initial load</span>
```

**2. CSS File:**

Create a separate file called `styles.css`. In that file create a rule:

```
span#note- {
  display: none;
}
```

Back in your HTML file, in between the `head` tags atop the file, link your stylesheet:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
```

Read more at [CSS display](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.php). In addition to `display`, you can also try the [visibility](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.php) property if you want the content to take up its space on the page but just not show the content.

In your case, once you have used one of these CSS methods to hide the element, it will be hidden on initial load of the page, and then your `showOnClick()` script should work to toggle the display on and off.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is correct you just need to call each function. I'm getting it to work correctly when I run the code like this.

```
function hideOnLoad() {
    var y = document.getElementById("note-");
    y.style.display = "none";
}
function showOnClick() {
    var x = document.getElementById("note-");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
        
showOnClick(); // Call onclick
hideOnLoad(); // Hide Span on default
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is the onload trigger, it won't work on a . You need to set your code like this, after your 2 functions:

```
document.addEventListener('load', () => {
    hideOnLoad();
})
```

That said, it would probably be better to set it as display: none; via CSS or style, and simply showing it when needed.